# Type inference with module

Tags: types, module, ocaml, inference

When trying to assign a variable with a type stated defined as int * int within a module:

```
let start : MazeProblem.state= (0,0)
```

I am getting an error message that the types are not matching.
(the problem came up trying out a search library from:
[https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/ocaml/ds/search.ml.html](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efilliatr/ftp/ocaml/ds/search.ml.html) )

```
File "search_test1.ml", line 34, characters 33-38:
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type MazeProblem.state
```

What needs to be done to get it working?

```
#use "search.ml" 

module Maze_FunctionalProblem = struct
  type move  = string
  type state = int *  int

  let success  s = let (x,y) = s in if (x==y && x==1)  then true else false
  let moves    (s:state) : (move * state) list  =
       match s with
       | (0,0) -> [ ("S", (1,0));("E",(0,1)) ]
       | (0,1) -> [ ("S", (1,1));("W",(0,0)) ]
       | (1,0) -> [ ("N", (0,0));("E",(1,1)) ]
       | (1,1) -> [ ("N", (0,1));("W",(1,0)) ]

  type table =  (state, int) Hashtbl.t

  let create (u:unit)  = Hashtbl.create 100
  let add  (t:table) (s:state) : unit = Hashtbl.add t s 1
  let mem  (t:table) (s:state ): bool = Hashtbl.mem t s
  let clear (t:table) = Hashtbl.clear t
end

module MazeProblem : FunctionalProblem = Maze_FunctionalProblem

module Test=FunctionalDFS(MazeProblem)

let start : MazeProblem.state= (0,0)
```

I would expect that type inference of OCaml detects that the (0,0) an int*int type is compatible with the defined struct.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], to ensure that the problem as described can actually be reproduced. The cause of the problem is likely that the definition of `FunctionalProblem` is hiding the definition of `t`. If so, just remove the type annotation. It isn't needed unless you deliberately want to hide information, and it doesn't sound like you do.

Comment: A note: `if expr then true else false` is a terrible practice as this is equivalent to simply `expr`. So `let success  s = let (x,y) = s in if (x==y && x==1)  then true else false` becomes `let success s = let (x, y) = s in x == y && x == 1` or even: `let success (x, y) = x == y && x == 1`. Also, `==` checks for p[hysical equality rather than _structural_ equality, so you probably want:: `let success (x, y) = x = y && x = 1`

Comment: Or since this only return true when both `x` and `y` are `1`:  `let success = function (1, 1) -> true | _ -> false`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Glennsl in comments and confirmed by viewing the linked `FunctionalProblem` module signature (shown below), the type of `MazeProblem.state` is *abstract*.

> ```
> module type FunctionalProblem = sig
>   type state
>   type move
>   val success : state -> bool
>   val moves : state -> (move * state) list
>   type table
>   val create : unit -> table
>   val add : table -> state -> unit
>   val mem : table -> state -> bool
>   val clear : table -> unit
> end
> ```

Looking at a much simpler example below, we can see the application of the `A` signature makes type `t` in `C` abstract. It is *not* abstract in `B` so we can directly use an `int` with `B.f` while attempting to do so with `C.f` causes a compilation error.

```
# module type A = sig
  type t
  val f : t -> t
end

module B = struct
  type t = int
  let f x = x + 1
end

module C : A = B;;
module type A = sig type t val f : t -> t end
module B : sig type t = int val f : t -> t end
module C : A
# B.f 5;;
- : int = 6
# C.f 5;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type C.t
```

Alternatively, we can expose the type of `t`.

```
# module D : A with type t = int = B;;
module D : sig type t = int val f : t -> t end
# D.f 5;;
- : int = 6
```

Comment: Thanks glennsl and Chris for your answers. That clarifies.In my case this helps: module MazeProblem : FunctionalProblem with type state = int * int = Maze_FunctionalProblem

Comment: On Stack Overflow you can say "thank you" by upvoting (once your reputation allows) and/or accept answers you feel have been helpful and answered your question.